Can I use pressure-treated wood to close gaps between shed and soil?
I'm looking for a way to close gaps between soil and shed deck. Can I use pressure treated wood, or it should be metal (since it touches soil)?
The goal is to restrict that area from animals, snakes etc.


Nice is very close to opinion.  Easy way would be wide enough pressure treated wood planks in a L shape to mount to the shed and cover the blocks.  1x12s?  Maybe mitre the corners and stain/paint with an accent colour to the shed.

What is your goal in covering these openings?  Aesthetic pleasing solutions might be very different than trying to keep animals from getting underneath.  Also, do you want it to be removable, or permanent?

Are you planning on doing something to finish off the top that's just bare pressure-treated plywood?  You'll want to do something that harmonizes with that.  If it were me, I'd probably do some sort of top edge with decking material (whether pressure-treated wood or man-made composite (aka Trex style of material), and then do continuous vertical pieces of the decking going down at least a few inches into the ground to dissuade digging animals from trying to go underneath.

Definitely check with HOA ahead of time, otherwise you may have to undo it

Already checked. That's why I'm saying it should be good

Ground contact rated pressure treated is an option. Pressure treated that is NOT ground contact rated is useless in contact with the ground (it will rot, a bit slower than untreated lumber.) Keep the little tags from the end of the lumber and your receipt somewhere you can find them again if it fails during its rated life. Without ventilation, it may trap excessive moisture under the shed.
Metal is an option. If animals out and ventilation in is desired, galvanized or stainless steel mesh. If you really want to keep animals out, with any approach, you can't just stop at ground level (they dig.) Classical "best method" is to go down a ways and out a ways (so if they dig down next to the outside of the above-ground mesh, they hit more mesh, rather than finding the bottom of the mesh and going in.)
